# expressions for 'controlled/run by a right or competent person'

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

I'm looking for expressions that mean 'to be controlled/run by a right, competent, or trustworthy person' as in a business, organization or company. Does 'to be in good hands' do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "in good hands" is a well-known and widely-used expression to mean that something is "*in the care of a person or people who are able to take care of someone or something well*". It would aptly describe a well-run business.

The adjectives you used in your question (competent, trustworthy) describe the *person* running the business. You could use adjectives or compound adjectives to describe the business, such as:

- Well-run
- Professional
- Tightly-run
- well-managed.